# Read-Only File C++

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to submit my homework assignment online and the professor wants it to be a zip file. When I go to zip the file it becomes a [Read-Only] file which is not what they want. Im using Visual Studios and also running it on a mac using parrallel desktop to run windows 10. Any suggestions on how to not make it a read only file?

Comment: *When I go to zip the file it becomes a [Read-Only] file which is not what they want.* Please explain, what do you mean by "I go to zip file" and what exactly becomes a [Read-Only] file.

Comment: It shouldn't do that. You are doing something wrong, or you are viewing zip folder without actually unzipping it. Either way this is not a programming related question.